# How to convert list into a dictionary by python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
old_list = [ ['ID0', 'ID1'], ['4', '8'], ['5', '6'] ]
```

I want convert list to new list

`key = ['id', 'frame', 'length']`

```
new_list = [{'id': 'ID0', 'frame': '4', 'length': '5'}, {'id': 'ID1', 'frame': '8', 'length': '6'}]
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: There 1000 similar questions with answers... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+convert+list+into+dict

Comment: I think a better question is how to finish this in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-line approach:

```
>>> [{'id':x, 'frame':y, 'length':z} for x,y,z in zip(*old_list)]
[{'length': '5', 'frame': '4', 'id': 'ID0'}, {'length': '6', 'frame': '8', 'id': 'ID1'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list=[]
for x,y,z in zip(old_list[0],old_list[1], old_list[2]):
    dict = {'id' : x, 'frame' : y, 'length': z}
    new_list.append(dict)
```

Comment: You can simplify it to one line by list comprehension: `new_list = [{'id' : x, 'frame' : y, 'length': z} for x,y,z in zip(old_list[0],old_list[1], old_list[2])]`

Comment: right, list comprehensions are good. Sorry but when I try new lines of code in a few seconds I use the basic form, and I leave list comprehensions at last for optimisation of the code. Thank you to have posted the correspondent list comprehension.